# how to see all operation when executing a batch?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

When executing a batch file, depending on where I execute it, I sometimes don't see the line executed. Right now I'm executing it in Jenkins in a workflow through a groovy script.

However in the batch file echo is on at the start, but I still don't see anything, just the final result?

How can I see every line being executed?

**Code:**

The code is just (it's for testing purpose only)

```
set bob=bob
```

and it doesn't display anything

Comment: Post the contents of that batch file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use **"Execute Windows Batch command"**

just call your batch file.

```
cd "directory"
file.bat
```

you can see every line of your batch execution using Jenkins **"Console Output"**

Comment: thanks for the answer!! The thing is I don't have a bat file, I'm making a Workflow in Jenkins, and I make batch through a groovy script (the only way to make it with Workflow). I write bat "MY BATCH CODE HERE"